# Hello, why i can not use vim command

Tags: node.js, vim, npm

can anyone help me with node.js and npm on windows. So my qustion is why i can not use 'vim' command in command prompt and node.js.Tahnks :)

```
>vim arguments.js
vim arguments.js
    ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Did you install vim in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `node` command, node javascript interpreter runs. Node cannot run external commands. Ensure that vim command in your PATH env. variable. If not, then add it manually. Else try to run it from default terminal (git bash or cmd). If you don't have vim, download it [here](https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim80-586.exe)

Answer (score 0):

you said you are on windows, vim/vi is the basic unix/linux editor ...